# Edit query clauses before exec (SQL Solution)

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have a long list API's call built based on a product table on my database, today we want to add a sub-product to this table (with adding a new table or an reflexive relation)

But we need to avoid to edit all API's Call / Query, is there are any solution under Mysql to Edit the clause of a query before execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually no direct answer to your question, but maybe it helps anyway.

You can create a **view**, which is like a virtual table. For example if you have the tables

```
product(id, attr1)
subproduct(id, subattr1, subattr2)
```

You can create a view like

```
CREATE VIEW legacy_products AS
SELECT
  p.id, p.attr, s.subattr
FROM
  products p LEFT JOIN subproducts s ON p.id = s.id
```

If you define the view carefully, you can avoid changes to your long list of API calls. But only if they consist only of `SELECT` queries. It is possible to make a view *updatable* but this is in general not true for a view over two or more base tables (like in the example).

SQLFiddle for playing around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85676/1
See this for view definition: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html